# uicache error - getcwd: Permission denied

Tags: ios, theos

When I run `make package install` to install my theos's application on iOS I got error:

> shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: Permission denied

And I try `su mobile -c uicache` via SSH, I got some.
I try only `uicache` I got no actions, my apps not show.
Finally my application doesn't show on springboard.